# Can I assign an ALIAS to a help option?

Tags: r, syntax, operators

In R, the I believe the core features such as "+" or "?" are called "operators" (they are I believe in most programming languages: an operator as a symbol to perform a calculation)

So I wanted to review the special variables such as `?` or `+`.  In R, the help is on the term "Syntax".

```
?Syntax
```

`Syntax` is unique in the realm of HELP as I do not believe it is a function.

If I wanted to create an alias to map `Syntax` to `Operator` or `Operators` (or `operator` or `operators` ... maybe even the same multivariate map on the word `Symbols`), how would I do that?

e.g.,

```
?Operators
```

I guess I could write my own wrapper function on help and have a dictionary of keys:values , but how would I override `?` to point to `my.help()` instead of the default `help()` function?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply over-write `?`:

```r
`?` <- function(e1, e2) cat('I will help with', substitute(e1))
```

For example:

```r
?plot
#> I will help with plot
```

If you only want special behaviour with certain topics, you can do something like:

```r
`?` <- function(e1, e2) {
  e1 <- deparse(substitute(e1))
  if(e1 == 'MyTopic') cat('I will help with', e1) else help(e1)
  }
```

Now `?` will work as normal, unless you do

```r
?MyTopic
#> I will help with MyTopic
```

Comment: What is `e2` doing?

Comment: `?` is unusual in R. It is actually parsed as a binary operator with two arguments, `e1` and `e2`. The `e2` argument is the one _before_ the `?` and the `e1` is the one after. The `e2` argument is allowed to be missing but the `e1` is not. In practice, we don't use the `e2` argument, though it is valid R. In fact if you type `lm ? plot` into the console, you will get the help file for `lm`, not the help file for `plot`. In any case, the `e2` argument is almost always missing, in which case `e1` is used to look up the help file.

Comment: If you type ```print(`?`)``` into the console you will see the source code for the `?` function